# Resolve where transient instance is shared

Tags: c#, ioc-container, structuremap

I have the following object graph that I would like to resolve using an IoC container:

[image]

Here, `B(#1)` and `B(#2)` are of the same type but different instances, same with `C(#1)` and `C(#2)`, and `D(#1)` and `D(#2)`. I would like to resolve `A`.

The problem is that there are two instances of `D` that four other objects have as a dependency. Depending on how I set the lifecycle of `D`, I will either get one instance that all of them share, or I will get four different instances.

I am currencly using StructureMap, but the solution could use another IoC container if some feature is needed that StructureMap doesn't have.

**The actual use case (as per request in the comments):**

The object graph is found inside a WPF application where I have separated the responsibilities of the typical MVVM ViewModel into a ViewModel and a Controller. In the image above, `D` is a ViewModel that only contains the state and `C` is a Controller that executes commands. `B` is the DataContext that the XAML binds to.

`B`, `C` and `D` are part of a user control. `A` is a DataContext that contains two instances of the user control.

Comment: Can you explain what's your actual use case? Why do you need this?

Comment: @Steven I've added the use case to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use factory method:

```
For<B>().Use(s => 
{
    var d = s.GetInstance<D>();
    var c = new C(d);
    return new B(c,d);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Since I left out some details in my question, I can't copy/paste your solution directly into my code. But the pointer to the `For` and `Use` methods give me enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick is to register `D` as per-request (which is StructureMap's default lifestyle) and make a registration for A that explicitly resolves the two B's:

```
For<A>().Use(s => 
{
    var b1 = s.GetInstance<B>();
    var b2 = s.GetInstance<B>();
    return new A(b1, b2);
});
```

This ensures that for each resolved graph of `B`, there will be exactly one `D`, and since your object graph probably consists of much more than just `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, this ensures that you only have to fall back to using manual wiring for `A` and this keeps your dependency graph the most maintainable.

Comment: Thanks. Kirill was a bit faster, so he got the answer check. Just wondering, won't `B` and `C` actually get different instances of `D` when you use per-request?

Comment: @TorbjörnKalin: By definition 'per-request'/'per-resolve' means just one instance for a call to `GetInstance` (the request), so you should get the same instance. The behavior you are describing is 'transient'. But you will have to test this yourself.